# Conversion of proofs between HoTT and ZFC

Tags: algorithms, formal-languages, homotopy-type-theory, proof-assistants, formal-proof

HoTT provides a foundation of math that remains mysterious for
many mathematicians including me. Hence this question.

There are several implementations of math based on ZFC, an
example being MetaMath. As well, there are several
implementations of math based on HoTT, some examples being Coq,
Lean, Agda.. etc.

In [1], Mario Carneiro provided an algorithm that converts proofs
written in HOL Light into Metamath. This makes me wonder if one
can, in principle at least, do so for proofs formulated based on
HoTT and ZFC. Or rather, put more precisely, can one in principle
write an **algorithm** that converts proofs between, say, MetaMath
and Coq?

#### Reference

- [1] [Conversion of HOL Light proofs into Metamath - Mario
  Carneiro](https://arxiv.org/abs/1412.8091)

Comment: Before you can even talk about converting proofs you have to first decide how to translate statements in HoTT to statements in ZFC. For example, what is the translation of the univalence axiom? Whatever it is, it is almost surely a non-obvious theorem in ZFC – assuming it is even provable in ZFC!

Comment: @ZhenLin Presumably one would go via a construction of a model of HoTT in ZFC, such as a simplicial or cubical model.  In that case the univalence axiom becomes a theorem about the model.

Comment: @MikeShulman That would be the obvious thing to do, certainly, and I would even guess it would work well if we assume there is a proper class of Grothendieck universes. But what if we don't have universes?

Comment: @ZhenLin Indeed as you said there should be obstacles, and that's the point of the question: to make a list of true obstacles, one can embed HoTT into ZFC if and only if each entry in which is overcome (or the other way around). Such a list will improve our understandings about the difference of the two systems, which will connect both communities in a concrete way.

Comment: @MikeShulman Could you elaborate what you mean by constructing a model of HoTT in ZFC? And in that case, can most theorems in HoTT be translated to theorems stated quite natively in ZFC (e.g. $1+1=2$)?

Comment: I think Carneiro's paper describes a "compiler" of HOL Light which "targets" Metamath by embedding HOL formulas in a natural way, and so on. It really does resemble a compiler, actually. But it seems like you are after a **transpiler** to translate HoTT into ZFC, and vice-versa.

Comment: Such as [Voevodsky's original model](https://arxiv.org/abs/1211.2851).  In this model the "sets" of HoTT become the sets of ZFC, so all the statements about sets that you prove in HoTT become the analogous facts in ZFC.